# How to create an alias for members of the current scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a piece of html which i use with ng-include. This template is used recursively and expects a scope/controller (sorry, i don't know the correct word in that case) with the name "element":

```
<div>
<span>{{element.name}}</span>
<div ng-include="mytemplate.html" ng-repeat="element in element.children"></div>
```

This works fine, but the root element is the member object of a controller with a different name:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as control">    
<div ng-howto="control.rootelement as element" ng-include="mytemplate.html"></div>
```

How can i pass my root element into the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ng-init` to pass data to a recursive template that expects object with a specific name:

```
<div ng-init="element = control.rootelement" ng-include="mytemplate.html"></div>
```